# Read and write data in BLE for LED turn on/off in swift

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am developing BLE with iOS.
I am using BLE service for LED turn on / off. I am able to read data but I am unable to send data to BLE device.
When I send 00 to BLE, LED should be turn off and when i send 01 , LED should be turn on for the BLE device.

Here is my code snippet.

```
 func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {

        if let characterArray = service.characteristics as [CBCharacteristic]! {

            for cc in characterArray {

                if(cc.uuid.uuidString == "FEE1") { //properties: read, write
                                                   //if you have another BLE module, you should print or look for the characteristic you need.

                    myCharacteristic = cc //saved it to send data in another function.
                    //writeValue()

                    peripheral.readValue(for: cc) //to read the value of the characteristic
                }

            }
        }

    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {

        if (characteristic.uuid.uuidString == "FEE1") {

            let readValue = characteristic.value
            print(readValue as Any)
            let value = (readValue! as NSData).bytes.bindMemory(to: Int.self, capacity: readValue!.count).pointee //used to read an Int value

            print (value)
        }
    }


    //if you want to send an string you can use this function.
    func writeValue() {

        if isMyPeripheralConected { //check if myPeripheral is connected to send data
            let dataToSend: Data = "01".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
            print(dataToSend)
            myBluetoothPeripheral.writeValue(dataToSend as Data, for: myCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse)    //Writing the data to the peripheral

        } else {
            print("Not connected")
        }
    }
```

How can i do it?

Comment: You are sending `<3031>`, not `<01>` (to quick check, `print(dataToSend as NSData)`. You write converting from a `String` to `Data` using UTF8, but when you read, you are converting to an `Int` The conversion isn't done the same way in both case. Use instead `let offInt = 00//or 01; let dataToSend = Data(bytes: &myInt, count: 1)`

Comment: Thank you so much :) it worked like a charm. I had tried this before        var newValue: Int = 00
let data = NSData(bytes: &newValue, length: MemoryLayout<Int>.size)           but it did not work.

Comment: I'm not a Swift expert, more Objective-C, but `MemoryLayout<Int>.size` is too big. You want the data to be smaller, that's why it failed.

Comment: Yes you are correct!!! I have seen on blog for MemoryLayout<Int>.size which is saying the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

swift 3

```
  var arrayReadWriteChar = [CBCharacteristic]()


    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {

        for newChar: CBCharacteristic in service.characteristics!{

            if newChar.uuid.uuidString == "FEE1"{

                self.arrayReadWriteChar.append(newChar)

                periphreal.readValue(for: newChar)

            }
        }
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {

        print("didUpdateValueForChar", characteristic)

        if let error1 = error{

            print(error1)
        }
        else{

            let value = [UInt8](characteristic.value!)

            print(value)    //whole array

            print(value[0]) //array object of index 0
        }
    }

    func writeValue(){

        if isMyPeripheralConected {

            let dataToSend: Data = "01".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!

            print(dataToSend)

            let command:[UInt8] = [0x01]        

            let sendData:Data = Data(command)

            myBluetoothPeripheral.writeValue(sendData, for: self.arrayReadWriteChar[0], type: .withResponse)
        } 
        else {

            print("Not connected")
        }
    }
```